# Facebook comment moderation tool

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I have just added the facebook comments plugin and I am seeing a first comment of a user.

But if I go to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments there isn't any recent comments.

Any clue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will want to make sure you've specified your Facebook App ID in the header section:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APP_ID}">
```

This will give administrators of your application in-line access (in my experience it takes a bit to show up, possibly due to caching).

Keep in mind that Facebook recommends this approach over doing an admins meta when using multiple boxes. From Facebook [seen here, scroll to Moderation Tools](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/):

> If your site has many comments boxes, we strongly recommend you
>   specify a Facebook app id as the administrator (all administrators of
>   the app will be able to moderate comments). Doing this enables a
>   moderator interface on Facebook where comments from all plugins
>   administered by your app id can be easily moderated together.

You can access this comment tool by going to the following link, after inserting your APP ID:

`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?id={YOUR_APP_ID}&view=queue`

Or by viewing the index [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments).

Comment: I have done as by your and fb instructions (which are the same) but I do not see comments in the moderation tool, it is empty :/ I use only fg:app_id tag. But when I click on "Moderation tool" above comment box on the blog  it opens the link in the form of https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/url/XXXX12341345/pending/descending/ where I see the comments only for that url obviously. What am I doing wrong? Btw, example website url is http://hocudabudem.fit/ishrana/osnove-ishrane/

Comment: Make sure to put `fb:app_id` and not `og:app_id`

Answer (score 6):

You will not be able to moderate any comment unless you add the following OpenGraph meta tag in your page's &ltmeta> section

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID"/>
```

So please check your page source that you have added the above meta tag. Only then you will be able to moderate comments posted on your page.

Comment: thanks the first comment has apperead, even tho i added the second meta tag available <meta property="fb:app_id" content=""/>

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it was resolved by having Facebook re-scrape the page using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/. You can see the Open Graph tags on that page so if your fb:app_id isn't there, it's not connecting commenting plug in with your moderation app.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure the `data-href` attribute is set correctly.  I was dynamically setting it and I was accidentally outputting the wrong domain. Once I corrected it, new comments now showed up in the comment moderation tool (though old comments vanished, since I was associating them with the wrong URL, haha).