# FB Comments Plugin App ID

Tags: facebook, plugins

I have followed the instructions on the fb dev website as well as searching for my problem on here and google, but I am still stuck.

I have managed to get a FB comments plugin working on a site and I can get the moderator function to work on the site but I cannot get the mod tools to through my facebook account (ie this link https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=queue)

It says I "Cannot edit global settings or moderation mode without fb:app_id" but I am unable to obtain an app_id. I generated the code using this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ but no app id was given. When I go to create my own app it asks me for credit/debit card information which I am not prepared to add. How do I find out what my app id is?

Much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can add your contact number in place of credit/debit card information to your account to validate your account and create app from it

Comment: Thank you for the reply; unfortunately I do not have a phone number as yet as I have recently moved country and am not paying for roaming so cannot receive any calls/sms to my mobile phone and do not have a landline. Surely there is a way around this other than using a payphone outside.

Comment: Check https://www.facebook.com/help/167551763306531/

Comment: Thank you Anvesh, your responses have been appreciated! 

If I were to verify my account, would I have to create a new app to obtain an ID for an app that is already in use? I have everything working on my site but I am restricted because "Global settings
Cannot edit global settings or moderation mode without fb:app_id" so isnt it possible to acquire the app id for an app for is already in use? Surely there must be away to do this?

Comment: You can try adding `<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>` in your `<head>` section as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) also check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797660/facebook-comment-moderation-tool). Although adding your id is not good idea if you want multiple different people to moderate your comments

Comment: I had already included that tag in there hence why I am able to use some of the moderator functions but not the global settings. Anyway thank you for your assistance, it is much appreciated even if I am no closer to getting an app id :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced that issue and resolved it with the following steps:

1. Make sure you are using the appropriate Facebook application (that
   means also to make sure you are not using *different* apps
   ids on the same page).
2. Make sure the app settings are correct (like the domain and website
   url).
3. Use the following HTML tags:

   ```
   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="app_id" />
   <meta property="fb:admins" content="facebook_user_name" />
   <meta property="fb:admins" content="another_facebook_user(if you have moderators)" />
   ```

   You can use other properties (but advanced that must match your website defined variables):

   ```
   <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
   <meta property="og:url" content="" />
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
   <meta property="fb:admins" content="" />
   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="" />
   ```