# How to delete facebook comments of other people on my site?

Tags: facebook

I implemented [facebook comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) on my site. I asked a friend to test it by commenting something, the comment appears. Now I want to delete it and I can't.

Any ideas how can I remove negative comments from my own site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the comment moderation tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

I think it needs the App ID in the header, see this thread: [Facebook comment moderation tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797660/facebook-comment-moderation-tool)

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APP_ID}">
```

Comment: It did not worked for me at first as I didn't set the current domain. Now it's working.

Answer (score -1):

If the Facebook comment in question was made on your wall then you can delete it on Facebook.
There is an X button that appears on hover for comments posted on your wall.

I do not know if there is an api for that.

Comment: I don't have facebook page. I have website

Comment: You can delete it on the comment page (that you linked) just hover over the right corner of the comment and an x will appear.

Comment: its not working, I only get the option to report spam, when clicking on the x

Comment: You have to report it as span before you can delete.

Comment: This is absolutely not true!

Comment: After marking a comment as spam the following message appears (for me) Post Hidden
Thank you for your feedback. This post will no longer show up for you. You can undo this, report this content as abusive or block Midhun Mayancheri.  To get it deleted you will have report the content as abusive.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49303/discussion-between-ilya-gazman-and-user3360944)