# Facebook comments | how can i review comments before they get published

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I am using "[facebook, comments widget](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments)" on my site

and wondering, how can I review comments before they get published?

- so i can delete unwanted ones, is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's simple. Add the tags `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID">` and `<meta property="fb:admins" content="your_profile_id"/>` if you haven't done so already, together with the other tags. If everything is right, the same comment box will have a "Settings" link on top. Click that, and select "let me approve each comment before it appears". There are many threads if you search. One discussion is here [Facebook comment moderation tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797660/facebook-comment-moderation-tool)